# How to preview a directory of images in (spac)emacs?

Tags: emacs, image-viewer

dired (or ranger which I prefer) is great for directory browsing, but what you see are basically the filenames, which is good for almost all uses... except when you're browsing your photos.

Does emacs have an actual image browser (something better than selecting individual images to browse) which would show all images in a directory and allow some actions on them (mark these 5 images for deletion, copy these 6 to another directory)?

Comment: [Image dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Image_002dDired.html) does this. More info on [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ImageDired).

Comment: Thanks @Juancho but I think that requires marking the images I want to preview first?

Comment: @Ng 
't' toggles all marks in dired

Answer (score 0):

In dired, [`dired-toggle-marks`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36255/how-to-mark-all-files-in-the-current-dired-directory) (just press `t`) to mark all files, then `image-dired-dired-toggle-marked-thumbs` (`C-t C-t`) in order to show the thumbs.